# GitHub pages not displaying linked html files

Tags: html, github

I deployed my GitHub pages site in the settings and the site works perfectly fine but i've linked many html files in the index.html file and those files are not displayed and i get a 404 error but the index.html file works fine what should i do?

https://i.slow.pics/t9MtN3YW.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check that the linked HTML file paths are correct?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying it seems i had capitalized the linked folder name everything's proper now <3